# automatización de ingreso en página con silverligth selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Hola a todos estoy tratando automatizar ingreso en python con selenium a una página a la cual debo ingresar de forma repetitiva por mi trabajo, la página tiene silverligth por lo que no me deja ver los input que estan en hidden, adicional a eso otro dato es que primero la pagina queda cargando y luego va a una de login en angular.

Este es el código que he creado:

```html
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.remote import webelement
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
cap = DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
cap['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True
opts= Options()
opts.add_argument("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.4; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0")
driver = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap,executable_path="D:\IEDriverServer.exe", options=opts)
url = "https://xxxxxx.com/"

driver.get(url)

user = "xxxxx"
password = "xxxxx"
time.sleep(60)
input_user = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//form/input[@name=__VIEWSTATE]")
input_pass = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//form/input[@name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR]")

input_user.send_keys(user)
input_pass.send_keys(password)

webelement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Lo que alcanzo a entender es que solo C# podría ser la solución, no puedo creer que Python no tenga la solución así que me he empecinado en hacerlo con Python algun pythonista que ande por allí que pueda ayudar por favor?????

Comment: ¿Pero te está dando algún tipo de error o algo? No tienen nada qué ver que la página esté programada en silverlight/angular con lo que hace selenium, que no es otra cosa que controlar un navegador para acceder a la página. ¿Qué esperas que haga `webelement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` (además de que dé error)?

Comment: no da error, no ejecuta el llenado con el user y pass  el enter es para entrar, todos los Input y botones están en hidden por ende los todas las cadenas y string asiganadas al tag , name id value parecen ser que vienen de algo programado en silverligth con java, la verdad desconozco bien si se trata de eso,

Comment: Esto es lo que muestra la pagina

Comment: Da igual en qué está programada la página. Selenium controla un navegador, no interacciona con el servidor. Lo que me temo es que la página de login no es la página a la que accedes inicialmente, con lo que no encuentra los inputs en el DOM original. Si es así, necesitarías trabajar con varias pestañas, lo que no sé si se puede con selenium.

Comment: la pagina solo se puede abrir en iexplorer y esta todo el DOM en hidden, solo muestra algunas cosas.

Comment: la pagina solo se puede abrir en iexplorer y esta todo el DOM en hidden, solo muestra algunas cosas.

Comment: Si el input está oculto no puede obtener el focus, por lo que no puedes enviarle eventos de teclado.

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo lo que necesitas es esperar a que aparezcan los inputs que quieres rellenar.

Puedes probar con

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
```

necesitas importar

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: sin resultados :(